# Как вывести количество активных слайдов Swiper&JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

Как вывести количество активных слайдов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример:

- в скриншоте 4 слайда активный (visible) и показывает 4 / 15;
- если юзер нажимает на кнопку Next, то так должно быть 5 / 15 в выводе;
- в мобильной версии должен быть 2 / 15.

Требуется решение только на `javascript`, `jquery` не подходит

Comment: _"Требуется решение..."_ Что Вы уже предприняли, чтобы выполнить это требование? [Отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1557048/edit) вопрос, приложив к нему разметку, стили и необходимые скрипты, чтобы можно было чётче видеть проблему.

Comment: у swiper уже есть плагин для вывода нумерации https://swiperjs.com/demos#pagination-fraction , но он не подходит, т.к показывает по одному.. в моем случае нужен в виде группе